# Is there a random page generator in storyboard mode Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, random, storyboard, generator

Hello I am making an app that requires a random page generator so I wanted to know if there was a way to add a random page generator to storyboard in xcode

Comment: What is a "random page generator?"

Comment: Something that when the user presses a button it takes you to a random page in the app.

Comment: yes you can program it if you are not going to be IB dependent.

Comment: Thanks and I have one more question, is there a limit to the amount of pages in storyboard mode. Like can I add thousands of pages if I wanted to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing out of the box that I know of (and given that every application has different concepts of "pages" I'm not sure that there *could* be a generic approach.  (I don't use storyboards, though, so I'm somewhat outside my comfort zone.)

It's easy enough to generate random numbers, which you could use as inputs to some method that will, say, pick out an indexed view controller and push it onto the navigation stack.  But this is hypothetical and entirely dependent on your application architecture.

Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is to generate random page (meaning view controllers) from a single command (e.g. Button) you can try this approach:

1. In the storyboard, simply link the homeviewcontroller to the numbers of random view controllers you intend to create, by pressing control-drag and select push as the segue.
2. Identify the numbers of segues independently, e.g segue1, segue2, ... segue100000 etc
3. Lastly, just key in the following coding according to your headers and implementation names;

For the header of the homeviewcontroller.h

-(IBAction)RandomButton:(id)sender

For the implementation of the homeviewcontroller.m

-(IBAction)RandomButton:(id)sender 
{

```
NSArray *segues = @[@"segue1", @"segue2", ... ,@"segue10000"];
NSString *segueID = segues[arc4random_uniform(segues.count)];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: segueID sender: sender];
```

}

1. Now try to run it. It should work fine! Cheers.